# Find out if a WPF CommandBinding is called from its shortcut

Tags: c#, wpf

In a callback method, i would like to know how a command binding was triggered. Most important I have to find out if a keyboard shortcut triggered the command, instead of a button or menu item being used.

This is my callback method:

```
private void AddObjectCommand_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
  yap.AddObject(false);
}
```

I assumed I could use the object parameter, but it's always the view (window) which is passed, not button or menu item.

I need this because the command should add a new object to my screen. If a keyboard shortcut is used, I would like to add the object at mouse position. If the menu shortcut is clicked, this is (obviously) not a good idea. The object should be added to the middle of the screen.

I could create two different commands, but by using only one the shortcut is also shown in the menu, which is preferable.

Comment: If you change your callback to use an ICommand (RelayCommand) within your viewmodel, then you can make use of the CommandParameter property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass some value in command parameter for identifying caller , and use **ExecutedRoutedEventArgs**  e to get that value.

```
public static class Commands
{
    public static readonly RoutedCommand testcommand = new RoutedCommand();
}

private void MyCmd_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     string parameter = (string)e.Parameter;
     MessageBox.Show(parameter);
 }
```

XAML

```
<Window.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding
              Command="{x:Static local:Commands.testcommand}"
              Executed="MyCmd_Executed"
            />
    </Window.CommandBindings>
    <Window.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Command="{x:Static local:Commands.testcommand}"
                     CommandParameter="From key Binding"
                     Key="H" Modifiers="Alt"/>
    </Window.InputBindings>

<Grid>
        <Menu>
            <MenuItem Header="My Command"
                      Command="{x:Static local:Commands.testcommand}"
                      CommandParameter="From bmenuitem"/>
        </Menu>
```

Comment: Thank you!  This is correct. It also works without x:Static so I'm not sure why you need to add that when you can just write Command="local:Commands.testcommand"

Answer (score 0):

> In a callback method, i would like to know how a command binding was triggered

I am afraid this information is not passed to the event handler. If you want to distinguish between keyboard shortcuts and other type of invocations, you should actually use two different commands.

They may do the same thing, like for example calling the same method, though. But there is no way to tell how the command was executed from within the `Executed` event handler.